# how to create a challenge between user and a friend similar to Facebook in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app where users have friends list. Now i have to create a challenge similar to facebook challenge where the user can finish the process(playing game) and he can challenge his friend and his friend can accept or deny the request and if accepted, after the process(playing game) finished the message to both user has to be sent which contains who has won.

How can i do this? please help me.

Comment: This doesn't sound too hard - you'll just need to create UI to set up the challenges and record the send / accepted / rejected state of the challenges in your database and send result notifications or emails. Which bit are you stuck with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a new model called `Challenge`. This might have a couple of associations:

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :sent_challenges
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :received_challenges
end
```

The corresponding associations on the `User` could be

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :sent_challenges,
    class_name: "Challenge", foreign_key: "sender_id", inverse_of: :sender

  has_many :received_challenges,
    class_name: "Challenge", foreign_key: "receiver_id", inverse_of: :receiver
end
```

Then you could perhaps have a method on your `User` to send a challenge

```
def send_challenge(friend)
  sent_challenges.create(receiver: friend)
end
```

You might have some actions on your `ChallengesController`:

```
def index
  @challenges = current_user.received_challenges
end

def create
  @challenge = current_user.send_challenge(params[:friend_id])
  # now the sender plays the game
  render :game
end

def accept
  @challenge = current_user.received_challenges.find(params[:id])
  # now the receiver plays the game
  render :game
end

def deny
  current_user.received_challenges.destroy(params[:id])
  redirect_to challenges_url
end

def complete
  # happens at the end of the game
  # work out the winner
  # send the emails
end
```

and of course you'll need to add the corresponding routes to hook it all up, and write views for the `index` and `game`. Maybe you'd put links on your friend list that directed to the `create` action so that people could issue challenges.

Notice how I put everything through `current_user.received_challenges` instead of just doing a basic `Challenge.find(params[:id])` - if you did that, *anybody* could accept the challenge just by guessing the id! Yikes!

I said "perhaps" and "maybe" a lot because there are different ways you could tackle this. But I hope that's enough to get you started. If not, I would suggest trying a Rails tutorial - [Michael Hartl's](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) is the classic.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I was just looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you got the `has_many :through` relation already?

You need to pass a `:source` to the users table because a user can also be a friend. This would look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :friends
 has_many :users, :source => :friend, :through => :friends
end
```

PS: You need to create the migration for the friends table and run it.

Its possible to add more columns to the join table (friends). There you could add the `relationship_status`. So that you have in the end:

**Friends Table**

```
ID | User_id | Friend_id | relationship_status
```

based on the `relationship_status` you can solve your issue!

Comment: I have already created friendship between users. I want to send challenges to friends. How can i do this?

Comment: If you got the friendship already then add a new colum to the friendsship table like "challange_status" and if a user sends a friend a challange then set this colum to "pending".

Comment: how can i send the challenge to friend as like sending friend request? Then as i have i said in the question i have to compare the results(score) and then display who has won.

Comment: Depends always on your code (which you dont posted so its hard for me..). Just find out the point where you want to send the challange request and then check the challange_status colum in the relationship talbe. If challange = pending .... else ...